# In journalctl internal grep, is it possible to specify option to only output matched pattern?

Tags: grep, journalctl, pcre

I have the following journal messages:

```bash
$ journalctl _COMM=kwin_wayland -o cat --since "-10s"
...
kwin_screencast: Dropping a screencast frame because the compositor is slow
kwin_screencast: Dropping a screencast frame because the compositor is slow
js: hello
goodbue
kwin_screencast: Dropping a screencast frame because the compositor is slow
kwin_screencast: Dropping a screencast frame because the compositor is slow
...
```

I want to extract only messages starting with "js: ".

From journalctl manual:

> -g, --grep=
> Filter output to entries where the MESSAGE= field matches the specified regular expression. PERL-compatible regular expressions are used, see pcre2pattern(3) for a detailed description of the syntax.

The normal grep can work in PCRE mode with -P option. And as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524845/7869636), I can use `-o` to only match pattern, and `\K` in pattern itself to drop the beginning. So this command:

```bash
$ journalctl _COMM=kwin_wayland -o cat --since "-10s" | grep -Po "js: \K.*"
hello
```

gives me pretty much what I want (unfortunately, it also cuts the next line of message).

I would like to use a single command, i.e. not piping to normal grep, but use the `-g` option of journalctl.

I can specify such pattern for internal grep:

```bash
$ journalctl _COMM=kwin_wayland -o cat --since "-10s" -g "js: \K.*" 
js: hello
goodbue
```

And it prints my message (fortunately, with next line of message). But it is with "js:" part. I want to drop it.

Is it possible to specify journalctl's internal grep option "-o" somehow?
Alternatively, I could use grouping in the pattern, but again, how do I specify that I want to output only that group?

Comment: Pipe into less and use & to search for lines that start with js (excludes lines without js).

Comment: Still require piping. I actually want to make a single command. Can you write how exactly "use & to search"?

Comment: `PCRE` library is one thing and the `-o` option of `gnu grep` is a different thing. As such, the `--grep` option of `journalctl` cannot print only the matching part. You have to post-process the output, either as you do it now or with a tool like `jq` e.g. `journalctl _COMM=kwin_wayland -o json --since "-10s" | jq -r ' .MESSAGE | select(startswith("js: "))[4:]'` will print only entries that match `js: ` but without that part.